# Define Factor variable with unobserved levels

Tags: r

I'm working with a dataset that has the following structure...

```
grades <- c("7A", "8B", "6C", "6B+")
```

...however there are a number of currently unobserved levels not in my dataset.  But I do not wish to have the factors defined automatically (so am using read.csv(..., stringsAsFactors=FALSE) when reading in my data). I would like to explicitly define the levels and their labels and convert the imported strings to be an ordered factor so that all grades are represented with associated counts of zero if none are observed.

```
real.grades  <- ordered(x = character(), 
                        levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17),                       
                        labels = c("6A", "6A+", "6B", "6B+", "6C", "6C+", "7A", "7A+", "7B", "7B+", "7C", "7C+", "8A", "8A+", "8B", "8B+", "8C"))
```

...but am struggling as to how to do this?

Suggestions and pointers gratefully received, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
grades <- c("7A", "8B", "6C", "6B+")

real.grades  <- factor(grades, levels = c("6A", "6A+", "6B", "6B+", "6C", 
    "6C+", "7A", "7A+", "7B", "7B+", "7C", "7C+", "8A", "8A+", "8B", 
    "8B+", "8C"))
```

Yielding:

```
> real.grades 
[1] 7A  8B  6C  6B+
Levels: 6A 6A+ 6B 6B+ 6C 6C+ 7A 7A+ 7B 7B+ 7C 7C+ 8A 8A+ 8B 8B+ 8C
```

For numeric representations use:

```
as.numeric(real.grades)
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks Tyler, that is indeed what I was after, got confused by the `labels=` option and thinking I needed to explicitly define them.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien cheers, I tried straight away on reading Tyler's answer, but was informed I had to wait 5 minutes before I could do that.  I've now waited and duly marked it as correct (just need to increase my reputation now and then I can join in properly ;-)